# How to solve $\log(x -1) + \log(x - 2) = 2?$

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms

I'm doing this exercise:

$$\log(x - 1) + \log(x - 2) = 2$$

My steps:

Step 1:

$$\log(x-1)(x - 2) = 2$$

Step 2:

$$(x - 1)(x - 2) = 10^2$$

Step 3:

$$x^2 - 3x + 2 = 100$$

Step 4:

$$x^2 = 98 + 3x$$

But I don't know what else I can do. In fact, I've doubts about the execution of $(x - 1)(x - 2)$?

Possible answers:

a) 1 b) 0 c) 3
d) -2 e) -3

This is a print from the book:

[image]

Comment: None of the possible answers is correct.

Comment: $x^2 −3x+2=100$ is equivalent to $x^2 −2\cdot1.5x+2.25=100.25$ that is $(x −1.5)^2=100.25$.

Comment: Here's my guess for how the equation in the book _should_ have been printed: $\log(x - 1) + \log(x - 2) = \log 2$.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah that makes sense! I think you could be right.

Comment: @Valeria Be aware that in many situations $log(x)$ means the natural log of $x$. Whether $log$ in the OP means base 10, depends on where you got the problem. BTW, if David K's guess is correct then it doesn't matter what the logarithm's base is, but if the book is correct, the base must $\sqrt{2}$, because as pointed out in one of the answers, c) is the only possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first show you a way to solve the multiple choice question, then I'll explain the general answer.

Do not forget to check the initial conditions! The function $\log x$ exists, over the reals, if and only if $x > 0$. Therefore you have that the final solution $x$ must satisfy $x > 2$. With this you can throw away most of the answers. The only one remaining is $3$, which, under normal conditions, would be the correct one. However, just by plugging it in the equation we see that it cannot be the answer.
I think that either there is an error in the book or that you didn't read it correctly.

In general, to solve a quadratic equation you can always make use of the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). You first have to transform you equation to the canonical form
$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0.$$

In your case, we have $x^2 - 3x - 98 = 0$, and the quadratic formula tells us that
$$x = \frac32 \pm \frac{\sqrt{401}}2.$$

You have to discard the solution with the minus because, as you will remember, there are some initial conditions for the existence of the logarithm.

Comment: I've added a print of the book. Thanks for the detailed answer. I think, there is a typo in the book.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explication.

Comment: @ValeriaGonzales Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 5):

After Step 3 you can subtract 100 on both sides such that the right hand side becomes 0 and then find the solution using the quadratic equation.

Comment: Doing that, I get: $x^2 - 3x - 98 = 0$. 98 can be decomposed into: 2 * 7 * 7... And with that i cannot resolve the ecuation. Any hint?

Comment: @ValeriaGonzales Do you know the quadratic equation that lets you solve a function of the form $ax^2 + bx + c =0$ (that is, a quadratic function) for given $a,b,c$? If not, check Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation .

Comment: Using that, I get as final answer: -7.01. Would you confirm that? So, I think the exercise is wrong, or the answers are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You've done everything correctly so far, from $$x^2 = 3x +98 \iff x^2 - 3x - 98 = 0$$ which gives us (using the quadratic formula) $$x = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{401}}{2}.$$

You'll have to discard the negative solution given the implicit impositions placed on $x$ through the logarithm. Now this doesn't match any of your options, which leads me to think that the original question is flawed in some way or there was a typo.

Comment: I've added a print of the exercise. I think, there is a typo.